# Build query using Spring Elasticsearch data repository

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, jpa, repository

I'm using elasticsearch 6, and Spring data jpa to query. I wrote this code:

1. Persistent Object:

```
@Document(indexName="vehicle_event", type="vehicle_event")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class VehicleEventEL {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private Long id_vehicle;
    private Long id_road;
    private Float latitude;
    private Float longitude;
    private String name_road;
    private Date timestamp;

}
```

2. Repository:

```
@Component
public interface VehicleEventELRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<VehicleEventEL, String> {

    Page<VehicleEventEL> findByTimestampBetween(String startTime, String endTime, Pageable page);

    Page<VehicleEventEL> findByTimestampBetweenAndId_vehicleEquals(String startTime, String endTime, Long id_vehicle, Pageable page);
}
```

The method `findByTimestampBetween` works.

The method `findByTimestampBetweenAndId_vehicleEquals` doesn't work and gives me the following error:

> Error creating bean with name 'vehicleEventELRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property vehicle found for type String! Traversed path: VehicleEventEL.id.

I don't find the solution.

Comment: lombok can be the culprit over here ..not sure...can you try the name as vehicleId in your class instead id_vehicle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscore is a problem and the solution is to follow java naming convention.
[Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) says:

> To resolve this ambiguity you can use _ inside your method name to
>   manually define traversal points. So our method name would be as
>   follows:
>
> `List<Person> findByAddress_ZipCode(ZipCode zipCode);`
>
> Because we treat the underscore character as a reserved character, we strongly advise
>   following standard Java naming conventions (that is, not using
>   underscores in property names but using camel case instead).

If you can't change the names, one of options is to use @Query annotation.